# mover los elementos dentro de un arreglo 2d de acuerdo al usuario

Tags: array, c

estoy tratando de intercambiar los elementos de mi arreglo 2d de acuerdo a lo que el usuario pida, por ejemplo: quiero cambiar de posicion el numero 1 con el 2 y luego imprimir la tabla.
me podrian decir que me falto o en que me equivoque ?
esto es lo que hice de mi codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define R 3
#define C 3
#include <time.h>
#define S 100
void swap( int q[3][3],int awa, int uwu, int awa1, int uwu1 )
{
 int comodin = q[awa][awa1];
    q[awa][awa1] = q[uwu][uwu1];
    q[uwu][uwu1] = comodin;
}

int main()
{


     int q[R][C]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

     int rr,cc,rrr,ccc, uwu, awa,awa1,uwu1
     ;
     rr=0;
     cc=0;

//PRINTS THE TABLE
            for(rr=0;rr<R;rr++){
            printf("\n");
            for(cc=0;cc<C;cc++){
                    printf("%d\t", q[rr][cc]);
            }
            }

            ///////////////swap////////////
printf("\nintroduzca su coordenada\n");
scanf("%i",&awa);
printf("\nintroduca su coordenada\n");
scanf("%i",&awa1);
printf("\nel otro\n");
scanf("%i",&uwu);
printf("\nel otro\n");
scanf("%i",&uwu);

    q[R][C]=swap(q[awa][awa1]&&q[uwu][uwu1]);

    for(rr=0;rr<R;rr++){
            printf("\n");
            for(cc=0;cc<C;cc++){
                    printf(" %d  ", q[rr][cc]);
            }
            }
```

Este es el codigo que llevo en mini

Answer (score 3):

El tienes dos problemas en este código, ambos en la función main.

1. cuando pides el último número, se lo estás asignando a `uwu` en vez de a `uwu1` (esto pasa sobre todo por no poner nombres comprensibles a las variables, como `rr`, `cc`, `R`, `C`, `awa`, etc, complicando mucho más la revisión de tu código. Pon nombres comprensibles que es gratis!!!).
2. La llamada a la función swap está mal. Tienes que pasarle la matriz y los cuatro números que has pedido introducir al usuario, separados por comas.

Esa parte del main tendría que ser así:

```
printf("\nintroduzca su coordenada\n");
scanf("%i",&awa);
printf("\nintroduca su coordenada\n");
scanf("%i",&awa1);
printf("\nel otro\n");
scanf("%i",&uwu);
printf("\nel otro\n");
scanf("%i",&uwu1); //<----- Este lo tenías mal.

swap(q,awa,uwu,awa1,uwu1); //<--- swap no retorna nada, así que no se asigna a nada
                           //y los parametros separados por comas.
```

Comment: "*Esto pasa […] por no poner nombres comprensibles a las variables*". Voy a aplaudir hasta que mis brazos sean muñones.

Answer (score 1):

Una función de *swap* (intercambio) debe intercambiar dos valores, ni más ni menos. En tu caso estás desarrollando una función de intercambio mucho más compleja de lo necesario sin aplicar el [principio de la mínima sorpresa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_la_m%C3%ADnima_sorpresa) (el resaltado es mío):

> Este principio establece que cuando dos elementos de una interfaz entran en conflicto o son ambiguos, **el comportamiento del programa ha de ser el que genere la mínima sorpresa por parte del usuario**. En particular, un programador debería pensar en **el comportamiento que menos sorprenda a quien use el programa en lugar del más natural para quien conozca su comportamiento interno**.

Las decisiones que has tomado al redactar la función *swap* es el equivalente a diseñar un coche que tenga las puertas en el techo: es sorprendente que un coche tenga las puertas en esa posición, los conductores no sabrán qué esperar de ese vehículo.

Tampoco estás siguiendo el [principio KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS) (el resaltado es mío):

> El principio KISS (del inglés *Keep It Simple, Stupid!*:​ «¡Mantenlo sencillo, estúpido!») es un acrónimo usado como principio de diseño.
>
> El principio KISS establece que **la mayoría de sistemas funcionan mejor si se mantienen simples que si se hacen complejos**; por ello, la simplicidad debe ser mantenida como un objetivo clave del diseño, y **cualquier complejidad innecesaria debe ser evitada**.

Las decisiones que has tomado al redactar la función *swap* es el equivalente a diseñar un coche que en lugar de tres o cinco puertas tenga nueve, haciendo que su fabricación y mantenimiento sea más complejo.

---

Así que tienes un coche con nueve puertas en el techo. ¿Qué podemos hacer para resolver este embrollo?:

1. Mínima sorpresa: Una función de *swap* (intercambio) debe intercambiar valores.
2. KISS: Para intercambiar dos valores, sólo necesitas dos parámetros.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int comodin = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = comodin;
}
```

Después, tal y como dice [SuperG280](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/309939/2742), usando una nomenclatura adecuada, puedes hacer la llamada pertinente:

```
int x1, y1, x2, y2;

printf("\nintroduzca su coordenada x\n");
scanf("%d",&x1);
printf("\nintroduca su coordenada y\n");
scanf("%d",&y1);

printf("\nintroduzca otra coordenada x\n");
scanf("%d",&x2);
printf("\nintroduzca otra coordenada y\n");
scanf("%d",&y2);

swap(&q[x1][y1], q[x2][y2]);
```

Siguiendo esos dos principios, no habrías cometido el error que te llevó a escribir tu pregunta.